# JGit equivalent to "git branch -a --contains <commit id> --merged"

Tags: git-branch, jgit

How can I replicate `git branch -a --contains <commit id> --merged` in JGit?

Below, I replicate without `--merged` but I'm not sure how to add the filter to only report branches to which the change was merged and not include all branches created after merge point.

If the command line can do, I expect JGit can too but I'm not sure how.

**Note**: the code below uses our GitController which is a wrapper around JGit, so some methods listed aren't pure JGit.

**Code**

```java
public List<String> getBranchesContainingCommit(File localWorkingCopy, String id, boolean onlymerged = true) {
  List<String> branches = new ArrayList<>()

  // Access Repository
  Git git = openExistingRepository(localWorkingCopy)

  // Find commit
  RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(git.repository)
  ObjectId foundId = git.repository.resolve(id + "^0")
  RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(foundId)

  // For all Remote Branches
  getBranches(git,true).each{ Ref ref ->

    if (walk.isMergedInto(
            walk.parseCommit(ref.getObjectId()), commit)) {
      branches.add(branchNameFromRefName(ref.name))
    }
  }
  walk.close()
  walk.dispose()
  return branches
}
```

**Test Error**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Wrong number of branches found
Expected:  [feature/branchContainsMerged, feature/branchContainsBase]
Actual:    [feature/branchContainsAfterMerge, feature/branchContainsBase, feature/branchContainsMerged, master] 
Expected :2
Actual   :4
  <Click to see difference>
```

**Test Case**

```java
  /**
   * 1. Create baseBranch
   * 2. branch branchMergedChangeSrc
   * 3. Make change
   * 4. merge branchMergedChangeSrc to baseBranch
   * 5. branch branchUnmergedChangeSrc
   * 6. Make change
   * 7. Branch branchAfterMerge from baseBranch
   *
   * Expect: with merges filter
   *   idMerged on branchMergedChangeSrc, baseBranch
   *   idUnmerged on branchUnmergedChangeSrc
   */
  String baseBranch="feature/branchContainsBase"
  String branchMergedChangeSrc="feature/branchContainsMerged"
  String idMerged = "f342575605aa297778047a940ac1f47b74c29d81"
  String branchUnmergedChangeSrc="feature/branchContainsUnMerged"
  String idUnmerged = "e1dbd1e371d60af235a1a0e82f95c25a9c0049b6"
  String branchAfterMerge="feature/branchContainsAfterMerge"

  @Before
  void setup() {
    controller = (GitController) getSCM(SCMType.Git)
    workspace  = createEmptyTestDir()

    // Clone Skeleton
    controller.cloneRepository(new File("testdata/skeleton.git").toURI().toString(), workspace)
  }

  @Test
  void mergedBranchesForMergedCommitTest() {
    List<String> containingBranches = controller.getBranchesContainingCommit(workspace, idMerged)

    // Unmerged Change on Branch
    checkBranches([branchMergedChangeSrc, baseBranch], containingBranches)
  }


  @Test
  void unmergedBranchesForMergedCommitTest() {
    List<String> containingBranches = controller.getBranchesContainingCommit(workspace, idUnmerged)

    // Unmerged Change on Branch
    checkBranches([branchUnmergedChangeSrc], containingBranches)
  }


  void checkBranches(List<String> expectedBranchNames, List<String> actual) {
    assertEquals("""Wrong number of branches found
Expected:  ${expectedBranchNames}
Actual:    ${actual}""", expectedBranchNames.size(), actual.size())

    expectedBranchNames.each { String branch ->
      assertTrue("Expected ${branch} in containing: ${actual}", actual.contains(branch))
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The flaw hear is in thinking that it is possible to limit a contains to branches where a direct merge took place.  All git can tell is which branches contain a commit by virtual of their history and which do not.

This seems to be done by walking from commit to HEAD of branch.  Branch head constantly moves forward and using "--merged" works only because at one point in time commit ID == branch HEAD.

Therefore, Attempting to replicate **--merged** is a bad idea as it won't yield the expected results.